# Eliminate render-blocking resources - Page Speed

Tags: javascript, css, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I'm trying to increase the performance of my site. I got about `~87` right now accordingly Google Page Speed Insight. While it's not the worst, it's not great either. One of the issues is I need to eliminate the render-blocking resources.

**Report**

[image: ![enter image description here]

I saw the potential saving that Google showed.

How do I mitigate this issue further?

As you can see, I already used the minified version of the static assets.

## I've tried

```
<script aync src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script aync src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<link  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="none" onload="if(media!=='all')media='all'">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" media="none" onload="if(media!=='all')media='all'">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Looks like you have a typo of async (aync), are you sure your scrips are being loaded in asynchronously?